# ignore ~/Homestead not working. Ignore symlink

Tags: php, laravel, git

I am running a laravel application.
I am not being able to ignore two specific folders/files.

```
~/Homestead
/bootstrap/env.php
```

Although I have added it to .gitignore, for some reason its not ignoring these two files/folder.

Comment: When you say ignore, what do you mean? I's unlikely that `~/Homestead` is in your project folder

Comment: @atymic its there. And even if I delete it, it isnt deleted. It must be because I am using vagrant.

Comment: What is the path of  your laravel project folder?

Comment: Are those folders already commited to your git repo?

Comment: The path is c:/Users/<username>/sites/myapp . Yes they are.

Comment: If you've already committed these files to the repo, `.gitignore` won't ignore them. That's only for ignoring files not committed yet.

Comment: If you want Git to ignore new changes to a tracked file, this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11366713/3216427